# Is it possible to draw a pattern (XABCD) with Tradingview api?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I am trying to build a harmonic pattern detection system. I would like to use Tradingview UI for frontend but I am wondering if it is possible to draw these patterns programmatically via their API.

On the chart, we can draw it manually, choosing tool from pattern toolbox. For example:
[bat pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wI51.png)

Can we manage to draw it with code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can draw complex shapes/drawings when using the [TradingView Charting Library](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/) by using `createMultipointShape()`:

```
tradingViewWidget.chart.createMultipointShape(
        // indicator points
        [
            {time: pointTime1, price: pointPrice1},
            {time: pointTime2, price: pointPrice2},
            {time: pointTime3, price: pointPrice3},
            {time: pointTime4, price: pointPrice4},
            {time: pointTime5, price: pointPrice5}
        ],
        // settings/overrrides
        {
            shape: 'xabcd_pattern'
        }
    )
```